# Use cases of RequestHandler.initialize() in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

Is it correct to say that one should use `initialize` method to prepare resources that will be shared by all other methods (e.g. `get`, `post`, etc) of a RequestHandler subclass?

What are the other common use cases for using `initialize` in Tornado? It'd be great to have some examples!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why you don't like [example in tornado](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/web.py#L194) code?

```
def initialize(self):
    """Hook for subclass initialization.

    A dictionary passed as the third argument of a url spec will be
    supplied as keyword arguments to initialize().

    Example::

        class ProfileHandler(RequestHandler):
            def initialize(self, database):
                self.database = database

            def get(self, username):
                ...

        app = Application([
            (r'/user/(.*)', ProfileHandler, dict(database=database)),
            ])
    """
    pass
```

Comment: @NikolayForminyh, I saw the example, and I understood it as you create a database connection outside the handler, and pass it to the handler on every request, so its `get` or `put` method can use it. Is there any other use case of `initialize`?

Comment: @skyork, what other use case you want? you can use it for anything, that must be available in request handlers and must be created before processing request.